# How to add adjacent subcontainers in Visio VBA?

Tags: vba, visio

I am trying to add a hierarchy of nested containers. I want to be able to add a subcontainer (B) to a given container (A), which may have other subcontainers (C), so that B and C will be adjacent to another.

I'm running into an issue where B is being nested in C. What I want is for B and C to be within A, but not within each other.

[image]

This is my code:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim shape As Visio.shape

    Dim cont As Container
    Set cont = New Container
    cont.InitializeClass "KeyA", "A"

    cont.AddSubcontainer "KeyB", "B"
    cont.AddSubcontainer "KeyC", "C"

End Sub
```

I have a class Container

```
Option Explicit
Private mName As String
Private mKey As String
Private mContainerShape As Visio.shape
Private mSubcontainers 'Dictionary
Private mX_coord As Double
Private mY_coord As Double

...

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mContainerShape = createContainer()
    Set mSubcontainers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeClass(pKey As String, pName As String)
    'Initialize with Setter so that container text title will be set too
    Me.key = pKey
    Me.Name = pName
End Sub

Public Function createContainer(Optional shape As Visio.shape = Nothing) As Visio.shape
    Dim Container As Visio.shape
    Dim doc As Visio.Document

    Set doc = Application.Documents.OpenEx(Application.GetBuiltInStencilFile(visBuiltInStencilContainers, visMSUS), visOpenHidden)
    Set createContainer = Application.ActivePage.DropContainer(doc.Masters.ItemFromID(2), shape)

    doc.Close
End Function

Public Function AddSubcontainer(subKey As String, subName As String)
    Dim subcontainerKey As String
    Dim subcontainer As Container
    Dim subcontainerShape As Visio.shape
    Dim subcontainer_row As Integer

    subcontainerKey = mKey & subKey
    Set subcontainer = New Container
    subcontainer.InitializeClass subcontainerKey, subName
    Set subcontainerShape = subcontainer.ContainerShape
    subcontainer_row = subcontainerShape.AddRow(visSectionProp, visRowLast, visTagDefault)

    With mContainerShape
        .ContainerProperties.AddMember subcontainerShape, visMemberAddExpandContainer
        .ContainerProperties.FitToContents
    End With

    mSubcontainers.Add subcontainerKey, subcontainer
End Function
```

I think the issue is occurring at the AddMember call in AddSubcontainer(). Even though it's adding a member to container A, it seems to be sticking it inside B.

Comment: Could you try to change cont.AddSubcontainer "KeyC", "C" to cont.AddSubcontainer "KeyB", "C"

Comment: That doesn't work, nor should I have expected it to. The key is used for identifying the subcontainer that is being added. cont is the container it should be added under. So changing KeyC to KeyB doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Peter, Although this question was posted quite long time ago, I would like to know, if possible, whether it was resolved or not since I am facing the same issue and I am blocked. If it was resolved, can you please share with us the updated solution/code?

Many thanks.

Comment: @PeterXu - I too am interested in knowing if you ever got a solution for this problem. Thanks.